# UENUM definition in header file

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I am trying to define a simple enumeration in a header file as per [the example published here](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Enums_For_Both_C%2B%2B_and_BP). My header file consists of the following:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"

UENUM()
enum class MyEnum : int32
{
    MyField1,
    MyField2,
    MyField3
};
```

If I remove `UENUM()`, the compiler doesn't complain; however, when I add it, I get multiple errors.

- expected a ';'
- expected a '{'
- identifier "MyField1" is undefined
- identifier "MyField2" is undefined
- identifier "MyField3" is undefined

This all seems odd considering I'm doing exactly what the article says to do and other websites suggest doing the same thing.

Here's what it looks like in my editor:

[image]

**What I've tried**

- Changing `enum class` to simply `enum`.
- Not explicitly specifying an underlying type.
- Defining the enum elsewhere (for instance, in one of my classes; but when you add `UENUM()` there, it tells you you can't define it there).

I am new to both C++ and UE4 so it could be silly or trivial. Either way, I'm having a hard time understanding why something so simple won't compile.

Comment: I don't know much Unreal, but reading through the example I see this comment which seems like it might be relevant: `//"BlueprintType" is essential to include` — did you try including that inside the parentheses?

Comment: I don't need it for BP so no. Examples elsewhere don't even mention it. When I defined it in a class, the compiler never complained about it so I doubt a missing argument is the issue.

Comment: Do you really get errors, or do you get red squigglies in your editor? Try compiling; Visual Studio doesn't actually understand how Unreal works, so it's pretty common for it to make red squigglies in places.

Comment: For anyone who may be experiencing this, in UE4 atleast I could only compile UENUMS with flags if the base type was uint8, and not int32.

Answer (score 2):

You would expect these errors if the macro `UENUM` is not defined, which means the compiler tries to interpret `UENUM() enum class` as a function definition.

I'm not familiar with the UDK API, but from browsing some examples it looks like the `UENUM` macro is defined in 'UObject/ObjectMacros.h', so you should include that file as well after CoreMinimal.h